# How to call the third div using CSS image HOVER

Tags: jquery, css, html

```
<div class="grow pic">
    <div class = "tooltip-wrap">
        <img src="some image.jpg">
        <div class="tooltip-content">
            <img src="someimage.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Hi, i need help i don't know how to call the image on  my css of grow pic overrides the size of the image.

i want to set my someimage.jpg to its 100%

heres the css

```
/*GROW*/
.grow img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px; 

  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.grow img:hover {
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}

.tooltip-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip-wrap .tooltip-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 20%;
  right: 10%;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: .5em;
}
.tooltip-wrap:hover .tooltip-content {
  display: block;  
}
```

Comment: Need some better explanation, also make a js fiddle

Comment: can you explain it using http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C67Jj/1/

Comment: [Here's your code](http://jsfiddle.net/timmah/ZLnkk/1/) with some borders added to show what's happening. Can you explain a little more what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as per html standard you need to close the html tags so far for your image tag it should be like this: `<img src="someimage.jpg" />`.

And for your requirement as I am understanding is to use just css:

```
.tooltip-content img:hover{
  width: 100%; /* or set max-width: 100%; to get maximum width of original image file*/
}
```

To accomplish your need using jquery(if you need), you could do like this:

```
$('.tooltip-content img').hover(function(){
  $(this).css('width','100%');
});
```

Even better solution would be provided if you clearly define your question.

Answer (score -3):

yeah, not sure I understand what you need, but setting the image to 100% could be

```
$('.tooltip-content img').attr('width','100%');
```

Assuming you are using jquery as tagged...

Comment: ..why would you use jQuery to set the width to 100% if you could do this with CSS...?

Comment: because he tagged the question with jquery? and because there are always many ways to do things and he didn't specify what he really needs. Of course I know you don't need jquery for this but it's NOT wrong to set it with jquery

Comment: even W3Schools has an example with does just that: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_attr.asp @JoshC

Comment: you're welcome. "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect." My answer is not sloppy, no-effort or clearly or dangerously incorrect. Maybe you would reconsider your down-votes first as well. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: If you want to play the tit-for-tat game, I encourage you to leave a comment on the answer that you downvoted to explain why you feel it fits your interpretation of the text you've quoted.

Comment: @BoltClock you are right. It's stupid and I will undo my evil. For a moment I was upset. I don't understand why people do downvote working solutions just because they don't like it.